# Is there a way of having something like jUnit Assert message argument in Mockito's verify method?

Tags: java, junit, assert, mockito, verify

Let's assume a snippet of testing code:

```
Observable model = Class.forName(fullyQualifiedMethodName).newInstance();
Observer view = Mockito.mock(Observer.class);
model.addObserver(view);
for (Method method : Class.forName(fullyQualifiedMethodName).getDeclaredMethods())
{
  method.invoke(model, composeParams(method));
  model.notifyObservers();
  Mockito.verify(
    view, Mockito.atLeastOnce()
  ).update(Mockito.<Observable>any(), Mockito.<Object>any());
}
```

`Mockito.verify` method throws an exception if a method in a model hasn't invoked `Observable.setChanged()` method.

Problem: without adding `loggers/System.print.out` I can't realize what's the current method that has failed the test. Is there a way of having something similar to `jUnit Assert` methods:

```
Assert.assertEquals(
  String.format("instances %s, %s should be equal", inst1, inst2),
  inst1.getParam(), 
  inst2.getParam()
);
```

---

**SOLUTION:**

```
verify(observer, new VerificationMode()
{
  @Override
  public void verify(VerificationData data)
  {
    assertTrue(
        format(
            "method %s doesn't call Observable#setChanged() after changing the state of the model",
            method.toString()
        ),
        data.getAllInvocations().size() > 0);
  }
}).update(Mockito.<Observable>any(), Mockito.<Object>any());
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This question is ancient, but Mockito v2.1.0+ now has a built-in feature for this.

```
verify(mock, description("This will print on failure")).someMethod("some arg");
```

More examples included from [@Lambart](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1339923/lambart)'s comment below:

```
verify(mock, times(10).description("This will print if the method isn't called 10 times")).someMethod("some arg");
verify(mock, never().description("This will print if someMethod is ever called")).someMethod("some arg");
verify(mock, atLeastOnce().description("This will print if someMethod is never called with any argument")).someMethod(anyString());
```

Comment: Using `org.mockito.Mockito.description` this way implies `times(1)`; you are verifying that the method is called, with the given arg, _exactly_ once. But you can do much more. If you want to verify it was called exactly 10 times: `verify(mock, times(10).description("This will print if the method isn't called 10 times")).someMethod("some arg");` or `verify(mock, never().description("This will print if someMethod is ever called")).someMethod("some arg");` or `verify(mock, atLeastOnce().description("This will print if someMethod is never called with any argument")).someMethod(anyString());`

Answer (score 20):

This does the trick (simple and clear):

```
try {
 verify(myMockedObject, times(1)).doSomthing();
} catch (MockitoAssertionError error) {
    throw new MockitoAssertionError("Was expecting a call to myMockedObject.doSomthing but got ", error);
}
```

Comment: Passing the cause as second argument is usally better than concatenating the message. `throw new MockitoAssertionError("message", e)`

Comment: MockitoAssertionError doesn't have a constructor with the parameters MockitoAssertionError(String, Exception) I use `new AssertionError("message", exception)` instead since this is the exception type that is thrown by JUnit for assertions.

Comment: Since 2.1.0 there is a `MockitoAssertionError(MockitoAssertionError, String)` constructor.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot do in mockito.
Mockito syntax makes very easy to test expected behaviour, but it has no concept of test state.

What you're trying to do is to have some information that are not in the mocked object when the mocks fails expectations.

If you really want to do, I see 2 general ways:
either you create your own verificationMode implementing the interface

```
org.mockito.verification;
public static interface VerificationMode
```

and adding a method like atLeastOnceMsd(String msg) that will show the message in case of failing or adding the current tested method in the model to the view object

for example with a similar line in the inner loop.

```
  view.setName("now we are testing " + method.getName());
```

Answer (score 3):

There isn't a direct API call that allows a message on verify. But I think if you change your verify signature to use the method object rather than Mockito.any(), the toString() on the Method class will kick in and give you what you want.

Something like this.

```
import static org.mockito.Matchers.anyObject;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.atLeastOnce;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;
import static org.mockito.Matchers.eq;

...

Observable model = Class.forName("class name").newInstance();

verify(view, times(1)).update(eq(model), anyObject());

for (Method method : Class.forName("class name").getDeclaredMethods())
{
    method.invoke(model, composeParams(method));
    model.notifyObservers();
    verify(view, atLeastOnce()).update(eq(method), anyObject());
}
```

Comment: Nice try, but it's not going to work. First method of the Observer#update(Object source, Object arg) is the model that is broadcasting the change not the method that has changed its state.

Comment: Just add the expectation you want to see. If that includes another type of observable then so be it.

Comment: You probably need to add more code that explains your class structure better.

Answer (score 1):

You could create matcher to print information on the current method. It's gonna be a bit clunky, but it will work print the method name when the verification fails.

Answer (score 1):

There is `org.mockito.internal.verification.Description` which delegates to provided `VerificationMode`, but allows to override verification message.

Answer (score 1):

you can use https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.2.6/org/mockito/verification/VerificationMode.html#description(java.lang.String)

eg.

```java
verify(mocked,times(1).description("This method is expected to invoke once")).someMethod();
```